# FireBasedb No properties to serialize found on class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am a newbie and i am trying to add some data in to the recyclerview from firbase db.but it showing the not serializable error. i searched everywhere and found couple of answers to make classes static and variables public but still not working, here  are my codes

My Adapter

```
 public class CardViewAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainpageCardModel,CardViewAdapter.Recyclerviewholder>{
    public Context mcontext;
    public List<MainpageCardModel> cakeslist;
    public CardViewAdapter(DatabaseReference ref){
            super(MainpageCardModel.class,R.layout.card,CardViewAdapter.Recyclerviewholder.cl    ass,ref);

    }


    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(Recyclerviewholder viewHolder,    MainpageCardModel model, int position) {
        viewHolder.ItemName.setText(MainpageCardModel.getItemName());
        viewHolder.ItemPrice.setText(MainpageCardModel.getItemPrice());
        if(MainpageCardModel.getItemImage() == null){
            viewHolder.CardviewImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mcontext,
                    R.drawable.ic_cake_dark));
        }
        else {
            Glide.with(mcontext)
                    .load(MainpageCardModel.getItemImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.CardviewImageView);
        }
    }

    public static class Recyclerviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView CardviewImageView;
        public TextView ItemName, ItemPrice;

        public Recyclerviewholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            CardviewImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cakepic_cardview);
            ItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caketitle_cardview);
            ItemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cakeprice_cardview);

        }
    }
```

My model class

```
public Class MainpageCardModel{
        public static String itemName;
        public static String itemImage;
        public static String itemPrice;
        public MainpageCardModel(){

        }
        public MainpageCardModel(String itemName, String itemImage, String itemPrice){
            this.itemImage=itemImage;
            this.itemName=itemName;
            this.itemPrice=itemPrice;
        }

        public static String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }
        public void setItemName(String itemName){
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

       public static String getItemImage(){
           return itemImage;
       }
        public  void setItemImage(String itemImage){
            this.itemImage= itemImage;

        }


        public static String getItemPrice(){
            return itemPrice;

        }

        public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        }
    }
```

My Fragment

```
private static final String TAG = "FreshCreamFragment";
    public static final String MENU_CHILD = "FreshCream";
    private String Cakename, cakeprice, cakeurl;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
  private CardViewAdapter adapterl;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    public List<MainpageCardModel> cakeslist;
    ProgressBar mprogressbar;
    MainpageCardModel mainpageCardModel;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
cakeslist= new ArrayList<>();
        adapterl = new CardViewAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MENU_CHILD));
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("menu");


mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MENU_CHILD).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String,String> cakedetails = (Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Cakename= cakedetails.get("Item_name");
        cakeprice = cakedetails.get("Item_price");
        cakeurl = cakedetails.get("url");

         mainpageCardModel = new MainpageCardModel(Cakename,cakeurl,cakeprice);
        cakeslist.add(mainpageCardModel);

        adapterl.notifyDataSetChanged();
mprogressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});


        };

   @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fresh_cream_fragment, container, false);
        mprogressbar = (ProgressBar) rootview.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.freshcream_recyclerview);
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterl);


        return rootview;


    }


}
```

MYdb
[mydbscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5splL.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have following lines in wrong order?

```
    adapterl = new CardViewAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MENU_CHILD));
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("menu");
```